# Stalk of tensor product sheaf is tensor product of stalks via adjunctions and abstract nonsense

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a ringed-space with sheaves of modules $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. I would like to show that for any point $p \in X$,
$$
\mathcal{F}_{p} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X, p}} \mathcal{G}_{p} \simeq (\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \mathcal{G})_{p}
$$
using the fact that left adjoints preserve colimits. I have shown an adjunction between the sheaf tensor and the internal hom functor. The problem is, this seems to only give me that the functor,
$$
- \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \mathcal{F}
$$
preserves colimits. Similarly I have the tensor-hom adjunction for modules over a ring, so I would ideally show this for the tensor product presheaf. But this still only gives me that 
$$
- \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)} \mathcal{F}(U)
$$
preserves colimits. But of course if I want to take a directed limit over open sets containing a point $p$, the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ will change as $U$ changes. Similarly I would also need the result for the bifunctor
$$
- \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} -
$$
to get the tensor product of both stalks. Is there any way to use this method to show that the tensor product sheaf commutes with taking stalks, or do I just need to do it manually?

Comment: What would doing it manually involve? I'm fairly certain that at some point you'll have to move some kind of colimit inside some kind of tensor

Comment: It is not a clear duplicate, but it basically answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222869/tensor-products-commute-with-inductive-limit

Comment: Use the answer linked in @MooS comments with the fact that $(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{G})_p=\varinjlim_{U\ni p}(\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(U)}\mathcal{G}(U))$. You can prove this equality using that taking stalks commute with the sheafification functor.